# Sed adding extra "\" character to tab

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am running in to an issue where sed is adding an extra character to my command.  Hopefully this is something easy but I can't spot the problem.  I am using OS X and `gsed` but I this same issues also occurs on Linux.

Here is the command I am running:

```
gsed  -i "/^bar/ a /\t test" test.yml
```

Here is what the `test.yml` file looks like:

```
foo
bar
foobar
```

After I run the above sed command, `test.yml` looks like this:

```
foo
bar
/    test
foobar
```

I have tried several variations of the above sed command (`\t`, `/\t`, `\/t`, etc.) but all of them seem to produce the extra `/` in the output file.  Why is this command adding an extra `/` character and how do I fix this?

Comment: Isn't the command `a \ ` (backslash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to append a line with text to your pattern space is

```
a \
text
```

In GNU sed, it also works on the same line, as in `a \ text`. You can either use

```
sed  -i 's/^bar/ a \ \t test' test.yml
```

or

```
sed  -i 's/^bar/ a \
\t test' test.yml
```

both of which work for me with GNU sed.

Even though not required, I used single quotes to avoid expansions of shell specific characters.

Comment: Splitting in to a new line was the issue.  I am not using any substitution but the rest of it works.

Comment: @jmreicha Really? Not the `/` vs ``\``?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't quite the truth.  It was a combination of both.  Your second command worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if gsed is any different from sed, but in sed you must add an 's' at the beginning of the substitution string:

```
> sed  -i "s/^bar/ a /\t test" test.yml

foo
a       test
foobar
```

Comment: It's not a substitution string, it's an address.